# Material Design Lite - misalignment of the textarea on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, material-design, material-design-lite

I'm using the Material Design Lite as framework in a project and after include some fields in a form, I noticed that the textarea element is aligned in all browsers except Firefox. I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/4284) in Google MDL Github warning about the problem but until now did not get back. This is how I insert the input and textarea fields on the markup:

```
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <textarea class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" rows="1" id="sample5"></textarea>
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample5">Text lines...</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me solve the problem without affecting the resize element?
The problem can be seen in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emanoellopes/trhye0tr/):

Comment: I don't see the issue in any version of Firefox on OS X. What version of Firefox and what Operating System are you on? Do you have any add-ons installed that might be messing with things?

Comment: In my work I use Windows 10 and Firefox 49 and in my house I use Ubuntu 14.04 and Firefox Nightly 47. I both cases I can see the issue. I did not tested in OSX yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an issue which depends on the operating system:

> The bug manifests on both Linux and Windows, but not OS X or Firefox for Android.
>
> I've filed Bug 1272430 to look into this upstream.

**References**

- [Mozilla Bug 1272430 – Styled textareas have inconsistent box sizing and rendering across platforms](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1272430)
- [Material Design on the GPU](https://mattdesl.svbtle.com/material-design-on-the-gpu)